# How are time translations understood in non-relativistic quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry

Let us consider nonrelativistic quantum mechanics, wherein Galiliean relativity reins supreme. This question is motivated by what I think is a misunderstanding I'm having in reading Fonda's *Symmetry Principles in Quantum Physics*.

Consider two different observers $\overline{O}$ and $O$ of a given quantum system $S$. These observers differ only in their time coordinate. Their time coordinates are related by  $\overline{t} = t - \tau$; that is,  $\overline{O}$'s time coordinate is delayed with respect to $O$'s.

Now Fonda suggests that in terms of how the two observers view the quantum system, the "translation" between the two frames of reference in their vectors (neglecting the ray technicality) used to describe a given state must obey
$$|(\phi_{\overline{O}}(\overline{t}),\psi_{\overline{O}}(\overline{t}))|^2=|(\phi_{O}(t),\psi_{O}(t))|^2.$$
My question is **how do we justify this requirement on the translation map**?
Do we argue that since $\overline{t} = t - \tau$ (since these are the same absolute times), we must have $\psi_{\overline{O}}(\overline{t}) = \psi_{O}(t-\tau))$ and so, trivially,
$$|(\phi_{\overline{O}}(\overline{t}),\psi_{\overline{O}}(\overline{t}))|^2 = |(\phi_{O}(t-\tau),\psi_{O}(t-\tau))|^2 .$$
Then by the unitary evolution of non-relativistic quantum mechanics, one has (if we evolve forward in time by $\tau$,
$$|(\phi_{O}(t-\tau),\psi_{O}(t-\tau))|^2 = |(\phi_{O}(t),\psi_{O}(t))|^2$$
and so we arrive at the required form.

The reason I am not sure about this is that Fonda says "In fact, the state of the system $S$ that $\overline{O}$ is observing at his time $\overline{t}$ is the evolved, through the time interval $\tau$, of the state observed by $O$ at his own time $t$", whereas my interpretation of what we have done is just opposite! I seem to have concluded that the state of the system $S$ that $\overline{O}$ is observing at his time $\overline{t}$ is the evolved **backwards**, through the time interval $\tau$, of the state observed by $O$ at his own time $t$ (since $\psi_{\overline{O}}(\overline{t}) = \psi_{O}(t-\tau))$).

The discussion in question is related to what Fonda discusses near equation 1.9 below.

[image]

Eq (1.3) alluded to is about the unitarity of time evolution (a hypothesis in nonrelativistic QM, I suppose).

[image]

Comment: What is e.q. 1.3?

Comment: Will update OP, one moment. Basically, unitary time evolution. @TobiasFünke

Comment: @TobiasFünke I don't think it's quite that. Like I say in the OP, I think there's a two step argument. In the first step, one uses that the two observers are seeing things at the same absolute time, and in the second step one uses that unitary evolution preserves inner products. But my problem, as per the answer by fulis which I still don't understand, is why in that first step we should be led to $\phi'(t) = \phi(t+\tau)$ rather than $\phi'(t) = \phi(t-\tau)$ (which is what I wrote in my OP).

Comment: Below (1.9), Fonda discusses two cases "in ordinary quantum mechanics". First, he says, two different observers are there who watch the system at the same objective (absolute) time and, I assume, the same position etc. Then, trivially, we have $\psi_{\overline{O}}(t) =\psi_{O}(t)$ so that (1.9) is trivially true. Fonda then refers to observers who differ in terms of their time only, but are otherwise at the same location. Suppose $\overline{O}$ has their time retarded by $\tau$: $\overline{t} = t - \tau$. One then has (and here I think is where I make my mistake according to fulis)...

Comment: ... that since they only disagree on time, we should have $\psi_{\overline{O}}(t) =\psi_{O}(t-\tau)$, so that trivially $|(\phi_{\overline{O}}(\overline{t}),\psi_{\overline{O}}(\overline{t}))|^2 = |(\phi_{O}(t-\tau),\psi_{O}(t-\tau))|^2 .$. If one then employs (1.3) on the RHS, we arrive at $|(\phi_{O}(t-\tau),\psi_{O}(t-\tau))|^2 = |(\phi_{O}(t),\psi_{O}(t))|^2$ which establishes (1.9). But my problem is that apparently $\psi_{\overline{O}}(t) =\psi_{O}(t-\tau)$ is wrong and it should be $\psi_{\overline{O}}(t) =\psi_{O}(t+\tau)$ according to fulis. This doesn't change (1.9), since one...

Comment: ...would just use (1.3) with backwards unitary evolution. But it does point to my misunderstanding. @TobiasFünke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're are using the wrong sign in the time-translation. If we write

$$
\phi'(t) = \phi(t-\tau)
$$

then $\phi'$ is translated *forward* in time with respect to $\phi$. This is because it's [a passive transformation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/609046/why-does-the-time-translation-operator-have-a-different-sign-than-the-time-evolu).

Thus, in the notation of the book (which only uses a single time coordinate) we have

$$
\mathbf{T}\mathbf{\Phi}_O(t) = \mathbf{\Phi}_{\overline{O}}(t) = \mathbf{\Phi}_O(t+\tau)
$$

and

$$
\left|\bigl( 
\phi_{\overline{O}}(t),\psi_{\overline{O}}(t)\bigr) \right| = 
\left| \bigl( \phi_O(t+\tau),\psi_O(t+\tau)
\bigr)\right|
$$

which is consistent with the statement in the book.

Note that it works the same [for other coordinate translations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_operator_(quantum_mechanics)). For example, for a wavefuction $\psi(x)$ we have the position basis state

$$
|\psi(x)\rangle = \int \psi(x) |x\rangle dx.
$$

Let $T|x\rangle = |x+a\rangle$. Then

$$
T|\psi(x)\rangle = \int \psi(x) |x + a\rangle dx.
$$

The displaced wavefunction is

$$
\langle x' | T|\psi(x)\rangle = \int \psi(x) \langle x'|x + a\rangle dx = \int \psi(x) \delta(x+a-x') dx = \psi(x'-a)
$$

Comment: So, if I am understanding you correctly, you are saying (I now use the same time coordinate like the book does so that it makes sense) that the fact that $t$ in $\overline{O}$'s frame *is the same as* the time $t-\tau$ in $O$'s frame (or, as you use, $t + \tau$ in $\overline{O}$'s frame *is the same as* the time $t$ in $O$'s frame) means that $\phi_\overline{O}(t+\tau) = \phi_O(t)$?

Comment: If so, does the rest of the argument make sense? That is, that in Step 1 we argue as above (that these describe the same system/same absolute time) and in Step 2 we argue using unitarity?

Comment: You're still using a forward translation. The backwards translation is $\phi_{\overline{O}}(t) = \phi_O(t+\tau)$. I believe this is what the author means with the quoted sentence, but I think it's worded in a confusing way. If your clock is retarded by $\tau$ units of time then that is the same as letting the system evolve for $\tau$ units of time while you pause your own clock. That's how I would phrase it. And yes, using the unitarity is correct.

Comment: I find myself still confused, I'm sorry. If the time in $\overline{O}$'s frame is the same as the time $t-\tau$ in $O$'s frame then we have $\overline{t} = t-\tau \implies \overline{t} +\tau = t$, right? This is what "retarded by $\tau$" means I thought? Then since what observers call their own times is immaterial, and they are examining the same system at some absolute time, we must have $\phi_{\overline{O}}(t) \equiv\phi_{\overline{O}}(\overline{t}) =\phi_O(t - \tau)$, where $\equiv$ is because our notation for variable is irrelevant and $=$ is because what...

Comment: ... $\overline{O}$ sees at his $t$ is exactly what $O$ sees at his $t- \tau$?

Comment: It is the _clock_ that is retarded in $\overline{O}$, not the system. If I move my clock one hour back, then the world (system) appears, to me, to be advanced by one hour. I think this is what Fonda is trying to say, and this is what $\phi_{\overline{O}}(t) = \phi_O(t+\tau)$ means.

Comment: I interpret "clock moving back" as "if $O$ says it's 8 am then $\overline{O}$ says it's 7 am, but of course what they call the *actual, absolute* time doesn't matter". Is this different than what you are saying?

Comment: No, it's the same. Let's say I'm $\overline{O}$ and you are $O$. My clock is retarded by one hour with respect to you, so while you see the sunrise at 8 am I see it at 7 am. That means that the state I see at 8 am is your state at 8 am advanced by one hour. This is exactly what Fonda says in your quote: "In fact, the state of the system $S$ that $\overline{O}$ is observing at his time $\overline{t}$ is the evolved, through the time interval $\tau$, of the state observed by $O$ at his own time $t$".

Comment: I *finally* see it, oof that was bad. Basically, I was getting confused with notation and the overloading of $t$. If the time is $t$ in $\overline{O}$ frame then it is $t + \tau$ in $O$ frame. Since these are the same absolute time, we must have $\phi_{\overline{O}}(t) = \phi_{O}(t + \tau)$. Does that comport with what you’ve been saying? Sorry it’s taken me so long to get this.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was trying to get across.

Answer (score 0):

There is a subtle confusion about your argument below

> ***Do we argue that since $\overline{t} = t - \tau$ (since these are the same absolute times), we must have $\psi_{\overline{O}}(\overline{t}) = \psi_{O}(t-\tau))$ and so***, trivially,
> $$|(\phi_{\overline{O}}(\overline{t}),\psi_{\overline{O}}(\overline{t}))|^2 = |(\phi_{O}(t-\tau),\psi_{O}(t-\tau))|^2 .$$
> Then by the unitary evolution of non-relativistic quantum mechanics, one has (if we evolve forward in time by $\tau$,
> $$|(\phi_{O}(t-\tau),\psi_{O}(t-\tau))|^2 = |(\phi_{O}(t),\psi_{O}(t))|^2$$
> and so we arrive at the required form.

Firstly, you are sure, there is an absolute time in the theory. in non-relativistic quantum theories, the symmetry group of spacetime is [Galilean Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_transformation), and its [representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Galilean_group). As a result, no time operator in non-relativistic quantum mechanics according to [Schur's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_lemma), or say, the existence of absolute time.

But the crucial missing is that,
$$\overline{t} = t - \tau\Rightarrow\psi_{\overline{O}}(\overline{t}) = \psi_{O}(t-\tau)   $$
is wrong. **The main reason is that a quantum state $\phi$ is a frame (observer)- dependent function in theory, and the probability amplitude is frame (observer)- independent which is an axiom in any quantum theory ([Wigner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_theorem)).**  The only thing we can read directly from $t,\overline{t}$ corresponding to a same absolute time is
$$|(\phi_{\overline{O}}(\overline{t}),\psi_{\overline{O}}(\overline{t}))|^2=|(\phi_{O}(t),\psi_{O}(t))|^2$$
If the we fix $\phi$ while running $\psi$ throughout the Hilbert space, we find
$$\phi_{\overline{O}}(\overline{t})=\phi_{O}(t)$$
as expected.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The point of my question is to prove, as Fonda says is possible, that $|(\phi_{\overline{O}}(\overline{t}),\psi_{\overline{O}}(\overline{t}))|^2=|(\phi_{O}(t),\psi_{O}(t))|^2$ obtains *as a theorem* in the case of time translations with Galilean invariance as the relevant symmetry group. Fonda then says that in more general theories we must *assume* (1.9) (i.e. postulate it). See the last sentence in the paragraph below (1.9). My question is thus about how one *proves* (1.9) in the time translation case in ordinary quantum mechanics, as Fonda says is possible.

Comment: We can't prove  (1.9) in fact. Since it is a fundamental assumption in theories, and it comes from the Galilean invariance $t\rightarrow \overline{t}$ of theory directly. The things we can do is prove something from (1.9).

Comment: Comments about the invariance of the theory.  If we believe the theory with some symmetries $S$, at the quantum level, the amplitude is invariant under those symmetry transformations. It is an axiom both on relativistic and non-relativistic quantum theories. A good reference is the https://www.amazon.com/Quantum-Theory-Fields-Foundations/dp/0521670535, in the chapter 2.

Comment: But Fonda is explicitly saying we can prove it (in the specific cases mentioned) in what I've attached?

Comment: It is a subtle point. We can prove (1.9) by symmetry. Since the theory is invariant under $t\rightarrow t+\tau, x\rightarrow x$. Meanwhile (1.9) itself is just the representation of symmetry, and thus we cant prove (1.9) from other things besides symmetry.

Comment: I think what @Lain is trying to tell you is that you *demand* $(1.9)$ to hold because you want that your (non-relativistic) theory (at this level about the world) has this property. And you argue the same for e.g. space translations etc.. (Galilean symmetries). To reiterate: This is what you impose "from the outside" on the theory. And in principle this is experimentally verifiable. It is the same in classical mechanics: There you would argue, for example, that your action/Lagrangian has some symmetry property, which reflects experimental and not mathematical facts.

Comment: I agree @TobiasFünke but I think Fonda is saying that if we assume Galilean invariance there is no need to demand this. Fonda says we do have to demand it more generally in relativistic theories though. I am trying to understand how Galilean invariance implies (1.9) in the restricted case of a pure time translation and think I am just confused about how that translation is effected mathematically, per the other answer. Perhaps I am not understanding you or Lain though.

Comment: @EE18 Step away for a moment from the text. You want to make predictions about experimental outcomes. You see in the experiments that all Galilean transformations leave the statistics invariant (at a certain level, of course; i.e. we know, for now, that SR is the way to go). To encapsulate this result mathematically, you demand 1.9/ generalizations thereof. This is nothing you can prove or derive; it is a mathematical condition which reflects experimental findings. From this equation, with Wigner's theorem and so on, you get the well-known results for e.g. time and space translation operators.

Comment: @TobiasFünke I completely agree that 1.9 is something we must demand, so perhaps let me rephrase. I think (and it's evidenced by numerous questions I've asked on here, but I still haven't understood it) that I have a fundamental misconception about transformations between coordinate systems. This question is largely a specific instance of that. That is, I want to understand exactly what Fonda is thinking/saying below (1.9) because I believe it bears on helping me understand time translations. I think Fonda is saying that we can obtain 1.9 *as a theorem* in this particular case of...

Comment: ...nonrelativistic time translations, and I suppose I want to understand *why*.